# How to compute sample size?

Tags: sample-size

For example: I want to survey a group of people to get the average time the call will ring before answered.

To calculate a sample size, I used the formula

$$ n = \frac{z^2 \times \text{Variance}}{(\text{Margin of error})^2} $$

eg. for a 95% CI and 5% margin of error and variance is 5 seconds

$$ n = \frac{1.96^2 \times 5}{0.05^2} = 7683.2$$

How do you interpret the $n$ here? Is it the total seconds we need to sample or will it be the number of people we need to sample?

Comment: It is difficult to read exactly what you have written as you have not used $\LaTeX$ and variance is likely to be measured in seconds squared rather than seconds, but $n$ is likely to be the number of samples (i.e. the number of people)